# TwoWayView android library how to set Margin (Spacing between images)? setItemMargin() not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using  [TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) library but i am not able to set the margin between the images. I have used the **setItemMargin(1)** but its not working.
When i pass big value(75,100) it increases the space between the images but when i try to set images very close to each other lets say 2 or 5 it doesnt work spacing will be same for all values below 10 default margin as shown in the picture below.

Code for adding view dynamically

```
   protected void showTwowayview() {

    // Get the welcome card layout and add this layout
    // below that.
    adapter = new HorizontalImagesBaseAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            ImageApplication.fromRecorderPaths);
    RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.welcomeCard);
    Log.d("in", "in");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 300);
    // Id of the view below which twoway view will be displayed
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.mannual);
    // set the layout margin
    params.setMargins(LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM);
    myLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    TwoWayView lparams = (TwoWayView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.twowayview, myLayout, false);
    TwoWayView twowayview = (TwoWayView) lparams.findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    myLayout.addView(twowayview, 0);
    //0 is the pisition off the twowayview in the layout
    TwoWayView listView = (TwoWayView) myLayout.getChildAt(0);

    //listView.setItemMargin(1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Twowayview View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/lvItems"
style="@style/TwoWayView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

In the screenshot below is what the minimum spacing i am getting. But i want images to be very close to each other. 
[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1):

Please Note that the value in pixel not DPI, so you need to convert the value from DPI to Pixel before pass it to the setItemMargin